# Make a Label Bold Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, label

How do I make a Label in Tkinter Bold ?

This is my code

```
labelPryProt=Label(frame1,text="TEXTTEXT")
labelPryProt.pack(side=LEFT,fill=BOTH,expand=False)
labelPryProt.configure(font=("Helvetica",BOLD, 18))#this is not working not making the text as bold
```

What is the error ?

Comment: no effect for  the same

Comment: NameError: name 'bold' is not defined

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You don't have to configure it separately, you can pass an argument when you are creating the widget:

```
labelPryProt = Label(frame1, text='TEXTTEXT', font='Helvetica 18 bold')
```

Comment: What if I have to change it later ?

Comment: Let's say I allow user to change the text type so how to configure that ? how to change it without declaring the variable again labelPryProt = Label()

Comment: Sure, than you'll have to configure it. `labelPryProt.configure(font='Helvetica 18 bold')`

Comment: @zzz123: the better solution is to use a font object, so you only have to change it in one place. See http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/fonts.html

Comment: This answer is definitely wrong. The question explicitly asks about making a tk Label bold. The answer here is about something else involving the Helvetica font and the font size 18.  =>   -1

Answer (score 17):

You have to put `bold` in quotes, like this: `label = Label(frame1, text='Hello', font=('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))` . This method works for me.

Answer (score 7):

Just put bold in the quotes, example : `label = Label(frame1, text = "TEXTTEXT", font = ('Helvetica', 18, 'bold'))`
That work for me, configure also work but you have to make one more line of code.
If you want, I can show you how to `.configure`:
Just add this code : `label.configure(font=("Helvetica","bold", 18))`

Thanks. :)

Comment: Here's your first upvote for suggesting `.configure`. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: It should be `label.configure(font=("Helvetica", 18, "bold"))`, not `label.configure(font=("Helvetica","bold", 18))`.